# Spring alternative for Factory

Tags: spring-boot

May be its a duplicate, Please feel free to tag... I am a newbie to Spring.

I am implementing a UserService for getting user details from different vendors, 
So My class Structure is

Interface UserService ->> UserServiceA, UserServiceB

Which user service to use depends upon a field called provider. my code will look something like

```
public interface ExternalUserService {
    ExternalUserDTO getUserDetail(String username);
}
```

Implementations -

```
public class GoogleUserService implements ExternalUserService{
    @Override
    public ExternalUserDTO getUserDetail(String username) {
        return user;
    }
}

public class FacebookUserService implements ExternalUserService{
    @Override
    public ExternalUserDTO getUserDetail(String username) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in my code in this fashion, I dont know if this is possible, but giving a try to see if its possible

```
public class ExternalUserManager(String provider) {
    String provider;
    @Autowired
    ExternalUserService service; //This is supposed to come from some factory, dont know how to get it in spring context.

    public void doSomething(String username) {
        System.out.println(service.getUserDetail(username));
    }
}


Had it been in conventional java programming, I would have created a Factory called UserServiceFactory, which would have made the things straight. 

Can someone please help me on how much it is possible with spring, and if its possible, then how can I achieve it? We use Spring boot, so no xml config.
```

Comment: Should it be possible that there can be a GoogleUserService and FacebookUserService at same Time?

Comment: Yes.. they are supposed to be used within same application instance. Like one user can have his both of the profiles linked to his account.

Comment: And why not Autowire both of them?

Comment: I am going to autowire both of them, but what I am not getting is how to get the appropriate bean based on provider?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. ExternalUserManager is Spring-Component (Singleton Bean). So setting a field provider would mean that everyone has the same provider. That: public class ExternalUserManager(String provider) is also not possible in Java.

Comment: Ok... ExternalUserManager is not a singleton bean. Its a Java component, but not desired to be singleton. The basic idea is, I have to get the appropriate UserService instance based on provider,I could write ExternalUserServiceFactory, but I want to know if there is a spring alternative.

Comment: If you want to autowire, then you have to set your Class as Spring(!)-Component an this is usually a Singleton-Bean. There are many possibilities to solve your problem, but I'm not sure what you want and if you really understand how Spring Framework and Components works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a @Bean annotated method with scope 'prototype' as a factory.
Spring will call this method anytime this bean is injected somewhere.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
...
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public ExternalUserService externalUserService(UserServiceFactory factory,UserProviderResolver resolver) {
    .. create the user service depending on resolver.getProvider()
}
```

The UserServiceFactory is used to create the specific service depending on the provider name, as you already described.

Create a class UserProviderResolver whith a method getProvider() that returns the provider name for the current request or user.

You can @Autowire the HttpRequest in the UserProviderResolver to get access to the current request.